# Can't use python gRPC rules in bazel - getting "Constraints from @bazel_tools//platforms have been removed" error

Tags: grpc, bazel, grpc-python

Trying to create a Python gRPC library, using gRPC v1.45.0 (upgrading could be complicated and also produced different issues; more on that in a moment). In my WORKSPACE, I have

```
load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")

grpc_deps()

load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_extra_deps.bzl", "grpc_extra_deps")

grpc_extra_deps()
```

When I attempt to build my gRPC library, I get the following bazel error:

```
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /usr/local/home/bill/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bill/254c50c69c3701cca4e904bef759573b/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:370:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: /usr/local/home/bill/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bill/254c50c69c3701cca4e904bef759573b/external/bazel_tools/platforms/BUILD:89:6: in alias rule @bazel_tools//platforms:windows: Constraints from @bazel_tools//platforms have been removed. Please use constraints from @platforms repository embedded in Bazel, or preferably declare dependency on https://github.com/bazelbuild/platforms. See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8622 for details.
ERROR: /usr/local/home/bill/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bill/254c50c69c3701cca4e904bef759573b/external/bazel_tools/platforms/BUILD:89:6: Analysis of target '@bazel_tools//platforms:windows' failed
INFO: Repository cython instantiated at:
  /usr/local/home/bill/depot/src/project/WORKSPACE:448:10: in <toplevel>
  /usr/local/home/bill/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bill/254c50c69c3701cca4e904bef759573b/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_deps.bzl:458:21: in grpc_deps
  /usr/local/home/bill/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bill/254c50c69c3701cca4e904bef759573b/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_python_deps.bzl:69:21: in grpc_python_deps
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /usr/local/home/bill/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bill/254c50c69c3701cca4e904bef759573b/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:370:31: in <toplevel>
```

I checked the bug; it suggests adding the flag `--incompatible_use_platforms_repo_for_constraints`. Adding the flag at build does not remove this error.

I tried upgrading my gRPC to a new version (1.50.0), and I get a different error on `grpc_extra_deps`: `Error in fail: go_register_toolchains: version set after go sdk rule declared (go_sdk)`. Apparently grpc_extra_deps also tries to set the version after grpc_deps, and I don't know how to make it not do that.

Both of these issues occur within the gRPC package itself, so I don't know how to get around it in my own build setup. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I traced this error down to a new release of bazelbuild (6.0.0).
You can force it to use the previous release by setting the environment variable

USE_BAZEL_VERSION=5.4.0

This fixed the error for me. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

For the first error please check whether you used any constraints in building it with grpc. Try using the [platforms](https://bazel.build/extending/platforms#:%7E:text=To%20help%20manage%20this%20complexity,of%20a%20system%2Dinstalled%20compiler.). 2. Remove if there are any [deps](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s/issues/709) used, if not solved then refer [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/2761)

Comment: This doesn't really explain what's needed to fix this error, or it assumes knowledge of Bazel that's beyond the grasp of us mere mortals.